# Unable to know when the sign in complete and get the user info in Firebase Auth web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am trying to add Google sign-in to my web application. I am able to open the redirect window for the popup, but am unable to know when the sign in is complete and get the user info. This is my code:

```
import {initializeApp} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.2/firebase-app.js";
import { getAuth,GoogleAuthProvider,signInWithRedirect,getRedirectResult } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.2/firebase-auth.js";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "...",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const auth = getAuth(app);
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider(app);

document.getElementById("sign-in").onclick = function() {
    getAuth().useDeviceLanguage()
    signInWithRedirect(auth, provider)

    

    getRedirectResult(auth)
        .then((result) => {
            // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access Google APIs.
            const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
            const token = credential.accessToken;

            // The signed-in user info.
            const user = result.user;
            console.log(user)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // Handle Errors here.
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            // The email of the user's account used.
            const email = error.customData.email;
            // The AuthCredential type that was used.
            const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
            // ...
        });
}
```

Comment: why are you mixing google web signin with firebase?

Comment: becuase that service is provided by firebase.

Comment: The comments in the code themselves actually states that  `// This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access Google APIs.` and `// The signed-in user info.` . This is where you must have get the user after a successful login. Have you tried printing these?

Comment: Yes @AyseAsude . But, it never reaches that line of code!